# TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string when using gensim.corpora.Dictionary()

Tags: python, dictionary, gensim

There is a dataframe like this:

```
  index  terms   
  1345  ['jays', 'place', 'great', 'subway']    
  1543  ['described', 'communicative', 'friendly']    
  9874  ['great', 'sarahs', 'apartament', 'back']    
  2456  ['great', 'sarahs', 'apartament', 'back']
```

I try to create a dictionary from the corpus of comments[ 'terms' ], but I face an error message !

```
from gensim import corpora, models
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary( comments['terms'] )

TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gensim: TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229360/gensim-typeerror-doc2bow-expects-an-array-of-unicode-tokens-on-input-not-a-si)

Answer (score 1):

Each index needs to have its terms be in a sublist, all of which are nested within larger list.

```
theterms = [['jays', 'place', 'great', 'subway'],['described', 'communicative', 'friendly'], ['great', 'sarahs', 'apartament', 'back'],['great', 'sarahs', 'apartament', 'back']] 

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(theterms)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert `comments['terms']` using `comments['terms'].tolist()` to a list and then run the corpora, it should work. You can do other preprocessing like stemming or stopwords removal etc. before creating your dictionary.