# How to input a series/list consisting of different tokens in a Gensim Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, typeerror, gensim

I hava a pandas dataframe that has one column with conversational data. I preprocessed it in the following way:

```
def preprocessing(text):
     return [word for word in simple_preprocess(str(text), min_len = 2, deacc = True) if word not in stop_words]

dataset['preprocessed'] = dataset.apply(lambda row: preprocessing(row['msgText']), axis = 1)
```

To make it one-dimensional I used (both):

```
processed_docs = data['preprocessed']
```

as well as:

```
processed_docs = data['preprocessed'].tolist()
```

Which now looks as follows:

```
>>> processed_docs[:2]
0    ['klinkt', 'alsof', 'zwaar', 'dingen', 'spelen...
1    ['waar', 'liefst', 'meedenk', 'betekenen', 'pe...
```

For both cases, I used:

```
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(processed_docs)
```

However, in both cases I got the error:

```
TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string
```

How can I modify my data, so that I don't get this TypeError?

---

---

Given that similar questions have been asked before, I've considered:

[Gensim: TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229360/gensim-typeerror-doc2bow-expects-an-array-of-unicode-tokens-on-input-not-a-si#33230682)

Based on the first answer, I tried the solution of:

```
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary([processed_docs.split()])
```

And got the error(/s):

```
AttributeError: 'Series'('List') object has no attribute 'split'
```

And in the second answer someone says that the input needs to be tokens, which already holds for me.

Furthermore, based on ([TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string when using gensim.corpora.Dictionary()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352552/typeerror-doc2bow-expects-an-array-of-unicode-tokens-on-input-not-a-single-str?noredirect=1&lq=1)), I used the `.tolist()` approach as I described above, which does not work either.

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently there were empty fields in my series/list object. The following code solved my problem: `processed_docs = processed_docs.dropna(axis = 'rows')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```html
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary([processed_docs[:]])
```

To iterate through the set.  You can write [2:] to start at two and iterate to the end or [:7] to start at 0 then go to 7 or [2:7].  You can also try [:len(processed_docs)]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me, but your suggestion still results in the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Question was posted long time ago but for anyone still wondering.
Pandas stores lists as strings hence the TypeError, one way of interpreting this string as a list is using:

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

And then:

```
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary()
for doc in processed_docs:
  dictionary.add_documents([literal_eval(doc)])
```