# GENSIM: 'TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string' when trying to create mapping for dictionary

Tags: ipython, nltk

my text looks as follows:

```
text=['paris', 'shares', 'concerns', 'ecb', 'language', 'eroding', 'status', 'currency', 'union', 
'diluting', 'legal', 'obligation', 'most', 'countries', 'join', 'ultimately', 'however', 'welcomes', 
'britain', 'support', 'more', 'integrated', 'eurozone', 'recognises', 'uk', 'euro', 'means', 
'obliged', 'choose', 'between', 'euro', 'pound', 'comment', 'article', 'moved', 'debates', 
'february', 'language', 'english', 'web']

from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

dictionary=Dictionary(text)
```

The error I'm getting:

> TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a
>   single string

I've tried to transform my text into a list of words to no avail. Also, I've tried to transform it to unicode to no avail. I'm no python expert just trying to analyse some text. My next step would be to check how often each token appears in the document called text. I'm using the ipython notebook.

Comment: there is a same question about yours. it may help: [Gensim: TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229360/gensim-typeerror-doc2bow-expects-an-array-of-unicode-tokens-on-input-not-a-si)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful.