# TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string

Tags: python, tokenize, gensim, corpus

I looked for all suggestion, where everyone says to break the string into tokens by split function. All that has been done already, but still it seems to have same error again and again.

```
for r in words:
        if not r in stop_words:
            processed_txt+=str(str(ps.stem(r) + " "))
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(processed_txt)
    #print(tokens)
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokens)
    #corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in tokens]
    print(dictionary)
```

So now it gives below error.

```
raise TypeError("doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a 
single string")
TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single 
string
```

and the output under "tokens" variable seems like this as below.

```
['becom', 'effect', 'willingli', 'without', 'need', 'obtain', 'knowledg', 'other', 'obtain', 'acquir', 'must', 'testamentari','claim', 'ownership', 'task', 'establish', 'endow', 'recept', 'willing', 'willsend', 'anoth', 'given', 'efficaci', 'presuppos']
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229360/gensim-typeerror-doc2bow-expects-an-array-of-unicode-tokens-on-input-not-a-si#33230682

Comment: As you can see,  tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(processed_txt) --- Here the words are already tokenised.

Comment: The link given by @MustacheMoses provides the answer. `corpora.Dictionary()` expects a list of lists, e.g. `[['words', 'for', first', 'document'], ['tokens', 'of', 'my', 'second', 'document']]`.

Comment: Yeah. fixed it. dictionary = corpora.Dictionary([tokens])